# Custom React classNames

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am struggling in trying to get my css to recognize the various css classes assigned to the const statuClass. Any help will be really appreciated. Below is my react code.

```
import React from "react";
import classes from "./TestLetter.module.css";

const TestLetter = ({ individualLetterInfo }) => {
  const { status } = individualLetterInfo;

  const statusClass = {
    correct: "test-letter-correct",
    Incorrect: "test-letter-incorrect",
    notAttempred: "test-letter-not-attempted",
  }[status];

  return (
    <span className={`${classes["test-letter"]} ${statusClass}`}>
      {individualLetterInfo.testLetter}
    </span>
  );
};

export default TestLetter;
```

**TestLetter.module.css**

```
.test-letter {
  font-size: 19px;
  line-height: 19px;
}

.test-letter-correct {
  color: #558b2f;
}

.test-letter-incorrect {
  color: #bf360c;
}

.test-letter-not-attempted {
  color: #f9a825;
}
```

Comment: pls use ``` ``` function for writing your code

Comment: Could you also share your code in TestLetter.module.css? Are the css of class like test-letter-correct in TestLetter.module.css or it is define else where?

Comment: Yes they are in TestLetter.module.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the module, just call the file: style.css and import it like this:
import './styles.css';

and use the code like this:

```html
<span className={`test-letter ${statusClass}`}>...</span>
```

Comment: It worked thank you very much, also what if I still wanted to you use module.css is it possible or this is the only way ?

Comment: yes it is possible, but i prefer using styled-component instead. the ideas are similar but styled-components is nicer in my opinion.

Comment: Ohh and I noticed on under “const StatusClass “ there was a typing error also for “notAttempred”, instead it should be notAttempted to match with the array status in the App.js